# Como chamar uma função mais de uma vez numa lambda expression?

Tags: expressões-lambda, foreach, groovy

No jenkins estou tentando ler um arquivo com groovy e para cada linha verificar se ela contém alguma das informações que preciso.

Dado o seguinte conteúdo de `arquivo`:

```
amarelo
verde
vermelho
azul
```

O código que tenho é esse:

```
    new File(arquivo).eachLine {
        linha ->
            contemInformacao(linha, "azul")
            contemInformacao(linha, "vermelho")
            contemInformacao(linha, "verde")
            contemInformacao(linha, "amarelo")
    }

    def contemInformação(linha, informacao) {
        if (linha.contains(informacao)) {
            echo "SIM"
        }    
    }
```

O resultado esperado seria:

```
SIM
SIM
SIM
SIM
```

Mas é impresso `SIM` apenas uma vez.

Penso que a função `contemInformacao` está sendo chamada somente a primeira vez.

Isso de fato acontece? Se sim, como posso fazer para ela ser chamada outras vezes para cada linha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente Jenkins não suporta todas as opções do groovy. Principalmente nas versões antigas.

Estou com a 2.241 e o código a baixo funcionou:

```
// usa o readFile fornecido pelo Jenkins
def file_text = readFile arquivo_path 

// o .each{} tem funcionado bem ultimamente, mas antigamente nao
file_text.readLines().each { linha ->
        contemInformacao(linha, "azul")
        contemInformacao(linha, "vermelho")
        contemInformacao(linha, "verde")
        contemInformacao(linha, "amarelo")
    }
}
```

Se isso nao funcionar, temo que terá que fazer "como antigamente". Algo do gênero:

```
def linhas = file_text.tokenize('\r\n')
for (int i=0; i < linhas.size(); ++i) {
   def linha = linhas[i]
   ...
}
```